multiple Visual Studio 2022 .net projects where remote origins are different gitHub accounts
I use Visual Studio 2022 Preview, and work on projects that are hosted on GitHub accounts for my work and for personal use. I have a GitHub copilot attached to my personal GitHub Account.
The issue I am seeing is that if I am working on a project where the origin is my personal GitHub, I just can't switch to work on a project that is associated to my work GitHub, because I then won't be able to push changes to my work GitHub. But if I log into my work GitHub in Visual Studio I lose copilot support.
Not sure how to fix this, It sounds counter productive if Visual Studio can only work on one GitHub account. I just started working with GitHub repos in VS. Previously it has been Azure DevOps accounts for personal and work, and i don't recall running into this issue pushing updates to the different remote origins.
Thanks in advance.
Update: I was able to accomplish what I want by following the instructions of this link https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-personal-account/managing-multiple-accounts#contributing-to-multiple-accounts-using-https-and-personal-access-tokens.
